# Only show upcoming events in fullcalendar list view

Tags: fullcalendar

I've got a simple FullCalendar setup, and I'd like to use a list view similar to Google's Agenda view, which is a list starting on the current date like so:

[image: gcal]

My current FullCalendar setup uses the listYear view, which starts at the beginning of the year and only shows the current year:

[image: fc]

How can I make a list view that:

- only shows upcoming events
- shows events for the next N months

FullCalendar code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultView: 'listYear',

            googleCalendarApiKey: 'xxxxxxxx',
            events: {
                googleCalendarId: 'xxxxx@group.calendar.google.com'
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultView: 'list',
            header: false,

            views: {
                list: {
                    duration: { days: 90 },
                    listDayAltFormat: 'dddd',
                }
            },

            googleCalendarApiKey: 'xxxxxxxx',
            events: {
                googleCalendarId: 'xxxxx@group.calendar.google.com'
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image: fc_fix]